# Error of JSONDecode while trying to get the response after hitting an API

Tags: python, json, base64, wav

As per the API the following data needs to be provided

```
data '{
    "data": <Clip Resource>,
    "quality": "x-high",
    "raw": "true",
    "precision": "PCM_32"
  }'
```

It will return a URL to the generated audio. If raw is set to true, it will return the raw WAV output encoded in base64.

The response will look like this:

```
{
"clip_url": <url to audio>,
"phoneme_timestamps": {
        "phonemes": [],
        "end_times": []
    }
}
```

The API is executed succesfully but i am unable to print the response.
For printing the response I am trying->
print(createClip.json())

but I am getting error as

---

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 print(createClip.json())

3 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Inspect the response to your API request.  It's likely that it is empty, or an error message formatted as HTML.

Comment: There are no error as I am getting a 200 response after hitting the API

Comment: So what's in the response then?

Comment: I am trying to print the response as -> print(createClip.json()) but getting an error: JSONDecodeError Traceback (most recent call last) in () ----> 1 print(createClip.json())

3 frames /usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx) 355 obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx) 356 except StopIteration as err: --> 357 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None 358 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)